# Reuse Eclipse's Plugin Manifest Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I want to have the **PluginManifestEditor** functionality in my view(not in a editor). Also I need to add some extra pages to it(along with the existing ones like Overview, Dependencies, runtime etc.).

I know that its implemented in org.eclipse.pde.ui plugin. I just started diggin in to the code and found that the javadoc is sparse and not much useful. I wanted to know

1. If someone has already done similar stuff or have some pointers or approach
2. Is there any abstraction in the code so that users can reuse it and also add thier own pages.

Any ideas of how it can be done?
Thanks already
.

Comment: How come there are no answers :(
If any other inputs are required, I could give that.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at `org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView` which is the ViewPart equivalent to a MultiPageEditor. To reuse parts of the PluginManifestEditor take a look at its `addEditorPages()` method - maybe you can reuse some of these pages, but I haven´t don´t anything yet.

Comment: @codeseavers...Thanks really. I will take a look over PageBookView, never came across that. As for addEdutorPages(), i have already digged that code, its so much coupled with editor and stuff.